# Create a function called addGrade

Tags: javascript

I need to Create a function called addGrade with the following params: index, grade 
that gets a student's index in the array and adds him a new grade.

I have array with all the object student and now I need to add grade to all the student by their id.

```js
var studentArray = [];
var grade = [];


function createStudent(id, age, firstName, lastName){
  this.id = id;
  this.age = age;
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName; 
  
}

var student1 = new createStudent(111, 36, "A", "A");
var student2 = new createStudent(222, 46, "B", "B");
var student3 = new createStudent(333, 56, "C", "C");
var student4 = new createStudent(444, 66, "D", "D");

studentArray.push(student1, student2, student3, student4);



function addGrade(id, grade){
  
    
}

console.log(studentArray);
```

How can I do this? I really feel lost!

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry for that. here is my code.

Comment: All you need to do is loop through the student array, check if the `student.id` matches `id` and if so modify `student.grade = grade`.

Comment: inside the function addGrade?

Comment: Yes inside the `addGrade` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a grade belongs to a student it would be better to add `grade` as a property to the `Student` object instead of a separate `grade` array. Then as indicated in my comment all you need to do is loop through the array, check if `student.id` matches the given parameter `id` and if so assign the `grade` given to the students grade `student.grade = grade`.

```js
var studentArray = [];

function createStudent(id, age, firstName, lastName){
  this.id = id;
  this.age = age;
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName; 
  this.grade = null;
}

var student1 = new createStudent(111, 36, "A", "A");
var student2 = new createStudent(222, 46, "B", "B");
var student3 = new createStudent(333, 56, "C", "C");
var student4 = new createStudent(444, 66, "D", "D");

studentArray.push(student1, student2, student3, student4);

addGrade(111, "A"); // Give student 111 a A
addGrade(222, "C"); // Give student 222 a C
addGrade(444, "B"); // Give student 444 a B
                    // Student 333 will have the default null value

function addGrade(id, grade){
    studentArray.forEach(function(student){ // For each student in the studentArray
      if(student.id == id)                  // If that student id matches the given id
        student.grade = grade;              // Assign the given grade to that student
    });
}

console.log(studentArray);
```